# RAM test to run on an embedded device

Tags: linux, embedded

I want to test RAM on my embedded Linux device for any kinds of problems. Can people suggest any RAM test suites out there?

I am working on ARM architecture.

Comment: What kind of device/OS/hardware? Not enough details.

Comment: device running embedded linux 2.6.31

Comment: If you can recompile the kernel then @Paul's suggestion is ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not plan on trying to test RAM while running Linux and virtual memory is active.  Another reason is that the kernel will lock down the memory it occupies, so that RAM would never get tested.

RAM has to be tested before the Linux kernel is loaded and executed.

U-Boot has a memory tester, and supports an assortment of architectures.

Comment: OK. IN that case do you the test strategy mentioned in the article is wrong ? http://www.netrino.com/node/154

Comment: @abc - a quick glance at that article indicates that it has good information.  My point (that does not seem to be mentioned in that article) is *when* (i.e. what stage in the boot sequence) should the memory test be run?

Comment: But there is no way to run the test mentioned in the article in the bootloader. Don't you agree ? And you recommended not running the any RAM tests after the system has booted. So, what should I follow?

Comment: @abc - No, I do not agree with your assertion that "there is no way to run the test mentioned in the article" before the kernel is loaded.  The last embedded Linux system I worked on had a four stage boot sequence: ROM boot -> second-stage bootloader -> U-Boot -> Linux.  I ran memory tests in U-Boot, before I- and D-caches and MMU were enabled.

Answer (score 1):

To save space you could enable the [in-built](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MEMTEST.html) memory tester in the kernel (included from 2.6.26 onwards).  Enable in your .config:

```
CONFIG_MEMTEST=y
```

Then have a boot option with a kernel with parameter `memtest`.  This will run through a battery of tests before booting normally.

Comment: Note that the mentioned code is under the arch/x86.  OP has not mentioned what arch his board has.

Comment: I am on ARM not x86. I updated the question. Thanks.